# Symfony 2.4 - PDOException]could not find driver: pdo_sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

For "reasons of fate", I need to build a small program, and to do it quickly, I will with symfony 2.4.

The program in question is connected to a SQLServer data base under a Windows 2008 server. But when trying to connect, I get error driver (with mysql never happened). My parameters.yml is like this (obviously there are important parameters modified)

```
database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
database_host: 10.244.xxx.xxx
database_port: null
database_name: imasuperprodatabase
database_user: wololo
database_password: epicpassword
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: secrettokenplz
database_path: null
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have access to php.ini in your server? Could you check if the dll for pdo_sqlsrv is enabled? Is the SQL server agent running?

Comment: i check this, but doesn't work